# Issue facing for Sharepoint online Authentication using javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

Using the code functionality in the link [Code](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2013/05/11/accessing-office-365-sharepoint-sites-using-rest-from-a-local-html-javascript-host/#comment-11991) to authenticate SharePoint online users using javaScript. I am facing an issue that- ajax call for Microsoft Login service which uses a soap request , returning an error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin '//--my sharepoint-public site--//' is
>   therefore not allowed access.

when I tried the ajax call using fiddler its working fine. but embedding the code in page is giving me an error. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Preflight request to the server - causing the issue- unable to resolve that .

Comment: Your first problem is [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: Thanks for reply @eirikb -although the login service and my sharepoint online site both resides on https- what else should i check or make change to make it work

Comment: I don't think __extSTS.srf__ supports CORS, I'm not sure what the author of your link used for testing, we could perhaps ask him: @pholpar ? I found another solution using [RST2.srf](http://jlattimer.blogspot.no/2014/04/soap-authentication-to-crm-online-using.html), but judging from the comments it seems to have the same problems.

Comment: @eirikb i tried with RST2.srf but no result. Comments on the above link is indicating that it was working with most of the user. Hitting the service from fiddler giving me the expected result , but from browser it is throwing error.

Comment: I tried with implementing  the over all code with simple html page(locally) but facing same issue/.

Comment: Is it a browser side issue or a server side changes is required to over  come this problem ?

Comment: Same-origin policy is browser only. To implement CORS you need server-side implementation as well. You could perhaps use a proxy (on same origin)

Comment: In this approach ,as we are using sharepoint online (no access over its server) unable to make the changes . But by making some  browser setting changes (Allow-content-access-cross-origin :enable) i can perform the operation which is not a feasible ,reliable solution.

Comment: For CORS issue in external web Service method(created by user -hosted on azure). Is it by creating an OPTIONS method service can solve the CORS issue??

Comment: If you make a proxy or a proxy-like service you only need CORS for this if you put it on another origin, but since you would control the proxy that wouldn't be a problem